# PushNotifications stop working after installing Community/FCM plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I am currently using **ionic capacitor PushNotifications** for Firebase cloud messaging. By the help of this I can get tokens.
Now I want to send notifications to all app users so I decided to use topics.

For this, I installed **community/FCM plugin**.

[capacitor-community/fcm](https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm)

I also made suggested changes in the **MainActivity.java** file, no error during app build.

But after installation this FCM plugin, PushNotifications(token) stop working.

Even below code starts always retuning false.

```
if (isPushNotificationsAvailable) {
      this.initPushNotifications();
    }
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file:-

```
package io.ionic.starter;

import com.getcapacitor.community.fcm.FCMPlugin;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(FCMPlugin.class);
    }});
  }
}
```

Here my fcm.service.ts File:-

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {
  ActionPerformed,
  PushNotificationSchema,
  PushNotifications,
  Token
} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
// import { FCM } from '@capacitor-community/fcm';

const isPushNotificationsAvailable = Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('PushNotifications');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FcmService {

  public topicName = 'project';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }

  initPush() {
    //This Plugin is not available on web

    if (isPushNotificationsAvailable) {
      this.initPushNotifications();
    }
  }
  // Request permission to use push notifications
  // iOS will prompt user and return if they granted permission or not
  // Android will just grant without prompting
  private initPushNotifications() {

    //console.log('Initializing HomePage');

    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
      if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // Show some error
      }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
      alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      //Store Devive Token in session variable
      this.storage.set("device_token", token.value);
      // FCM.getToken()
      //   .then((r) => alert(`Token ${r.token}`))
      //   .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      // now you can subscribe to a specific topic
      // FCM.subscribeTo({ topic: this.topicName })
      //   .then((r) => alert(`subscribed to topic`))
      //   .catch((err) => console.log(err));      
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
      //alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationReceived',
      (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        //alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      },
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        // alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
        const data = notification.notification.data;
        //console.log('Action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification.notification));
        if (data.detailsId) {
          this.router.navigate(['/bid-project', data.detailsId]);
        }
      },
    );
  }
  //Reset all Badge count
  // resetBadgeCount() {
  //   PushNotifications.removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
  // }
  // move to fcm demo
  // subscribeTo() {
  //   PushNotifications.register()
  //     .then((_) => {
  //       FCM.subscribeTo({ topic: this.topicName })
  //         .then((r) => alert(`subscribed to topic ${this.topicName}`))
  //         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  //     })
  //     .catch((err) => alert(JSON.stringify(err)));
  // }

  // unsubscribeFrom() {
  //   FCM.unsubscribeFrom({ topic: this.topicName })
  //     .then((r) => alert(`unsubscribed from topic ${this.topicName}`))
  //     .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  // }
}
```

After removing community plugin token generation started working as before.
Please tell me what wrong is with my code.